# Turn based multiplayer - google play hangs?

Tags: android, multiplayer, turn

I have written a turn based multiplayer game, built around the tbmp skeleton app. Everything works...usually. However, once in awhile this bit hangs:

```
public void onCheckGamesClicked(View view) {
Intent intent = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getInboxIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES);
}
```

All I see (when that happens, which it usually doesn't) is the spinning wheel. I can go back to the screen where this is called, and click another button to start a new game (for instance), and that works. So my connection doesn't seem to be the issue. But if I retry this, I get the spinner. Finally, the only way to "fix" it is to restart the phone. (That is...signing in and out of Google play does nothing. Quitting the app does nothing.)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing this on two different devices.  When it happens, you can open the Play Games app itself and it *also* shows the spinner.  No amount of clearing data/force stopping seems to help.